# Custom Nodes Variables Not Being Stored

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, pynodes

I am having an issue while working on a custom node tree. When I create a variable in self on a custom node it is not available in other functions of that class, for example:

```
from .base_node import  Base_Node
from bpy.types import Node


class Test_Node(Node, Base_Node):
    bl_label = "Test Node"

    def init(self, context):
        self.outputs.new("tree_mesh_socket_type", "Tree")
        self.inputs.new("tree_socket_type", "Tree In")
        self.Test_Bool = False

    def On_Execute(self):
        print(self.Test_Bool)
```

I get the error:

```
line 14, in On_Execute
print(self.Test_Bool)
AttributeError: 'Test_Node' object has no attribute 'Test_Bool'
```

This happens where ever I define the variable, it is only accessible from the function it is created in.

Am I just misunderstanding how the node classes work or is this a bug? Should I be using a different method to store the data?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: my 0.02c worth: Using `TestNode` and `test_bool` would IMO sit better with blenders API style convention. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define it outside of the functions to make it a property of the class. Try adding something like the following before your 'def's :

```
class Test_Node(Node, Base_Node):
    bl_label = "Test Node"
    
    #Define class-level property
    Test_Bool: bpy.props.BoolProperty() 

    def init(self, context):
        .....etc.
```

This will define a new class-level property 'Test_Bool' and this should then be available as 'self.Test_Bool' from any of the functions within the class.

Comment: Might be worth adding a few lines of code around that one line just to give a bit of context as to where, specifically, this line of code should be placed.

Comment: How would that work for an instance of a class? As in ```  Class_Instance = My_Class("Example parameter")```

Comment: Thanks@RayMairlot - good suggestion.

Comment: @Dragonpeak - I'm not sure, but it should work the same. The key is to define it at class level rather than within the function. Perhaps that would be a question more suited to a Python group rather than Blender.

Comment: But as the properties used are from blender, bpy.props.etc, and as far as I know only blender objects can be in properties, via props.PointerProperty(). How would a non blender class be used? Anyway, thanks for the help.

Comment: For example, `Test_Class: My_Class` does not work, giving the same attribute error as before and `Test_Class: PointerProperty(type=My_Class)` only works for blender registered classes.

Comment: @Dragonpeak It would be helpful if you could provide an example of your 'My_Class' situation. Perhaps ask a new question for that since the original one was specific to variables, not classes.